# Perl complaining about uninitialized value in regex

Tags: perl

I have a function below:

```
sub getMinFromParam {
    my ($param) = @_;

    print "PPPP = $param\n";

    my $min;
    if ($param =~ /\s*\[(\S+),\s*(\S+)\]\s*/) {
    print "IN HERE\n";
        $min = $1;
    }
    elsif ($min =~ /((\w+),)+/) {
        my @tmp = split (/\s*,\s*/, $param);
        if ($tmp[0] =~ /\[(\w+),\s?(\w+)\]/) {
            $min = $1;
        }
        else {
            $min = $tmp[0];
        }
    }
    return ($min);
}
```

When $param is a string like: 120u, 421u, 53, 19, 41u, 53,
I get the error: Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at this line:

```
if ($param =~ /\s*\[(\S+),\s*(\S+)\]\s*/) {
```

Why is it complaining about uninitialized value when $param is defined?

Answer (score 1):

It's not. It's complaining about this line:

```
elsif ($min =~ /((\w+),)+/) {
```

At least here with the test data `120u, 421u, 53, 19, 41u, 53`

Which is expected, since `$min` is only set if `$param` matches, but the `elsif` only runs if `$param` doesn't match.

That line is probably supposed to be `elsif ($param =~ /((\w+),)+/) {`, in which case I don't get a warning.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually `$min` that is undefined, and it gets reported when you use `strict` and `warnings`. This fixes it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub getMinFromParam
{
    my ($param) = @_;

    print "PPPP = $param\n";

    my $min;
    if ($param =~ /\s*\[(\S+),\s*(\S+)\]\s*/)
    {
        print "IN HERE\n";
        $min = $1;
    }
    elsif (defined $min && $min =~ /((\w+),)+/)
    {
        my @tmp = split (/\s*,\s*/, $param);
        if ($tmp[0] =~ /\[(\w+),\s?(\w+)\]/)
        {
            $min = $1;
        }
        else
        {
            $min = $tmp[0];
        }
    }
    return ($min);
}

getMinFromParam "120u, 421u, 53, 19, 41u, 53"
```

Comment: I just realized the same issue... But I don't get it though... Why would the Perl interpreter complain about the "if" instead of the "elsif" that was actually causing the problem. I had use warnings; at the top of my code as well.

Comment: @AlvinHo: I'm not psychic. However, on my system the error message included the proper line number _as well as the relevant statement_ `Use of uninitialized value $min in pattern match (m//) at ./test.pl line 16.` Now I'm guessing you might be getting a clobbered linecount because of here documents, a [source filter](http://linux.die.net/man/1/perlfilter) or a special way of launching the script not directly on the source file as is (?). Oh, and linecontinuation characters (in HERE docs?)

Comment: @Alvin, First, there is no such thing as an `elsif` statement. Secondly, `if` has been special-cased to give warnings mid-statment many many years ago. Upgrade your Perl.

Comment: @ikegami: thanks for coming up with likely reallife explanation :)

Comment: That should have read "there is no such thing as an `elsif` statement, so you can't say the warning is not coming from the `if`."